# PHP - get uncertain number of fields

Tags: php

I have a problem with `<form>` in php .

i have uncertain number of fields `(inputs)` . it may be 1 or 100 input field .

Is there any function or class to get uncertain number of fields ?

Comment: `$_POST` would just contain all of them...? unsure of what you're asking

Comment: $_POST would contain all of them and then you can process them as per your need

Comment: I guess question here should be how to generate uncertain number of fields and how to retrieve their values when the form is posted..

Comment: `foreach` and check for any set/non-empty values inside that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
echo '<form>';
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo '<input name="field[]" value="',$value,'">';
}
echo '<input type="submit"></form>';
```

If you send that form, `$_POST['field']` will be an indexed array in which every entry will correspond to one of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

$_POST would contain all the fields from the form on submit

`print_r($_POST)` will display them in an array for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array name for the input fields in your form. For example, you can make an array of `title` fields by adding `[]` after the name:

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" />
<input type="text" name="title[]" />
<input type="text" name="title[]" />
```

Now in your PHP code, this value will be an array containing an amount of values equal to the number of fields with this name. The following code would print all `titles` on separate lines:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['title'] as $value)
    echo $value . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count the `$_POST` or `$_GET` what you use.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "The total number of input fields is";
echo count($_POST); // include submit also
}
?>
```

Comment: *"`// include submit also`"* - That is not always desired, nor IMHO should be included, where I've answered a few questions about OP's not wanting a submit button/input be part of the inclusion, *just saying*.